# Insert UTF-8 value in mysql using Cascading

Tags: mysql, cascading

I am using Cascading 1.2. I am trying to insert data into mysql using JDBCTap. Some of values are in utf-8 and other values are not in utf-8 format.
The values which are in utf-8 decode format are being inserted in mysql as "???" like this.

I have created table as charset utf-8 still its not getting inserted properly.

what is the solution for this problem ? How to insert both types of values in mysql using JDBCTap ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You can prefix [string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-literals.html) with a character set introducer, e.g. `_utf8'my utf-8 encoded string'`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get answer.

Comment: In cascading flow, I have set following values : 1. Source Tap : source path, 2. Pipe : Contains "Each" pipe 3. TableDesc : contains column names and definition for the columns, 4. Sink Tap : using JDBCTap. TableDesc is passed as an argumrnt to JDBCTap. Where to apply solution suggested by you in this scenario ?